# Vue v-for not rendering shadow correctly in slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, vue.js

I am trying to use [iDangero.us](https://idangero.us/swiper/) Swiper in my Vue project. Everything is working fine except the shadow in slide. After every pagination the shadow goes bigger and bigger and darker. After the circle is over and I am back at **second** slide the shadow resets itself to normal again.

Here is illustration, what is going on:

[image]

This is what I am doing:

```
<template>
  <div class="product-slider">
    <div class="product-slider__wrp swiper-wrapper">
      <product-slide :item="item" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"/>
    </div>
  <div class="product-slider__pagination"></div>
</div>
</template>



  data() {
    return {

      swiperOptions: {
        vertical: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        effect: 'fade',
        loop: true,
        mousewheel: {
          invert: false,
        },
        // autoHeight: true,
        pagination: {
          el: '.product-slider__pagination',
          clickable: true,
        }
      },
    };
  },

  mounted(){
    const swiper = new Swiper('.product-slider', {
      spaceBetween: 30,
      effect: 'fade',
      loop: true,
      mousewheel: {
        invert: false,
      },
      // autoHeight: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.product-slider__pagination',
        clickable: true,
      }
    });
    swiper.slideTo(3, 1000, false)
  },
```

This is the slide component:

```
<template>
<div class="product-slider__item swiper-slide">

  <div class="product-slider__img">
    <inner-slick-slider :images="item.imageUrl" :imageTitle="item.title | decrypt"/>
  </div>

  <div class="product-slider__content">
    <span class="product-slider__code"> test </span>
  </div>

</div>
</template>
```

And this is the shadow on the slide component: `box-shadow: 4px 13px 30px 1px rgba(112, 137, 249, 0.2);`

I tried everything I could find from google. Also tried to re-render on updated and beforeUpdate etc.. What I am doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hey can you add product-slide template code here

Comment: Your box-shadows probably stack. Where did you apply it? Quickly looking through the api I found that the active slide has a class called `swiper-slide-active`. Try setting the box-shadow for this class.

Comment: @joy Hey! I added the slide component's code also. It pretty much just has the html structure, no script logic. I am applying the shadow to the `.product-slider__img`

Comment: also in whch class you have applied this box shadow css ??

Comment: @joy [This CodePen](https://codepen.io/JavaScriptJunkie/pen/WgRBxw) is pretty much the full example, it has the same problem, even tho it doesn't use v-for and vue at all. The suggestion you gave helps alot, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi, actually the issue is coming because of transition and box-shadow
>   CSS.

In code, CSS is applied to all div so i have removed it and added box-shadow only on img which is currently active right now.

I have added box shadow css here.

```
&.swiper-slide-active {
  .blog-slider__img {
    box-shadow: 4px 13px 30px 1px rgba(252, 56, 56, 0.2);
    img {
      opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: .3s;

    }
  }
```

and removed box shadow css from below class.

```
&__img {
     // width: 40%;
    width: 300px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(147deg, #fe8a39 0%, #fd3838 74%);

    border-radius: 20px;
    transform: translateX(-80px);

    overflow: hidden;

    &:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(147deg, #fe8a39 0%, #fd3838 74%);
      border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Here is link of updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJQbmo).

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp updated description please review it. issues are coming because of transition and box-shadow CSS.. you can use browser inspect option and look where CSS is applied...

Comment: So you basically moved the `&__img` block out of `&.swiper-slide-active`? I do not understand that because those `&__img` was out of `&.swiper-slide-active` before also, correct me if I am wrong. I just couldn't find the difference :D I know I sound stupid in that situation. But I am glad your version works perfectly :)

Comment: Basically, I have added box shadow only for an active image which is visible now and remove from all images. @TarvoMäesepp

Comment: Okay, I see now. Thank you very much again 